# ggplot2で凡例とプロット色を一致させた状態で、凡例項目順を変更させたい。

Tags: macos, r, tidyverse, ggplot2

おそらく、うまく検索をかけたら、解決策が見つかるのかもしれませんが、
私にはたどり着けませんでした。
ご教授のほど、お願いいたします。

Rでtidyverseとqiime2Rを用いて作図を試みています。

```
metadata<-read_q2metadata("metadata.tsv")
pco<-read_qza("unweighted_unifrac_pcoa_results.qza")

colpal<-c("red","blue","magenta","deepskyblue","maroon4","darkgreen","orange","blueviolet","honeydew4","black","salmon4")

pcou$data$Vectors %>%
  select(SampleID, PC1, PC2) %>%
  left_join(metadata) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, color=`wks`, shape=`experiment-Sex`)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.7, size=3) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,17,15,18,18), name="Experimental priod-Sex") +
  scale_color_manual(values=colpal, name="Post inoculum day") +
  guides(shape=guide_legend(order=1), color=guide_legend(order=2)) +
  ggtitle("Unweighted UniFrac") +
  theme(aspect.ratio=1, plot.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold"))
```

reference: Plotting PCoA
https://forum.qiime2.org/t/tutorial-integrating-qiime2-and-r-for-data-visualization-and-analysis-using-qiime2r/4121

[image: UniFrac PCoA]

この、色の凡例を日数順にするため、

```
scale_color_manual(values=colpal, name="Post inoculum day", labels=c("1d","2d",...,"Origin_inoculum") +
```

と「scale_color_manual」の部分に「labels」を加えると、
凡例の日数項目名は希望通りの順番になるのですが、描画のプロット色と一致しなくなります。
（1dが赤、2dが青...となってしまう）

どこを修正すれば、描画プロットと凡例が一致するようになるのでしょうか。

ちなみに、「Experimental priod-Sex」は三次元描写と一致できています。

補足情報が足りないようでしたら、コメントにてご指示ください。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

ヘルプの `values` 引数の説明に

> The values will be matched in order (usually alphabetical) with the limits of the scale, or with breaks if provided.

とあります.

色を指定する `values` を設定したならば, 対応する `wks` 列の値がなんであるのか `breaks` で指定する必要があります. 設定しない場合, ソートした順などになるため対応関係がおかしくなることがあります. そして `labels` はあくまで凡例のラベルを上書きするためのもので, 対応関係を指定するものではありません.

よって, `breaks` にも `labels` に指定したものと同じものを指定してください.

`shape` の表示が正しいのはたまたまソートしても順番が変わらないためだと思います.

例:

```r
g <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + geom_point()
g
g + scale_color_manual(values = c("red","blue","magenta"), labels = c("versicolor", "setosa", "virginica"))
g + scale_color_manual(values = c("red","blue","magenta"), breaks = c("versicolor", "setosa", "virginica"), labels = c("versicolor", "setosa", "virginica"))
```

**補足**: `breaks`, `values`, `labels` にそれぞれ与える他に, `values` に名前付きベクトルを与えることで `breaks` と  `values` の対応関係を指定できるため, 以下のような書き方も可能です.

```
g + scale_color_manual(
  values = c(versicolor = "red", setosa = "blue", virginica = "magenta"),
  labels = c("versicolor", "setosa", "virginica"))
```

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html

Comment: `breaks`引数というものがあるのですね。勉強になります。ありがとうございました。